# extensions of the did package

Tags: r, function

Good Morning everyone,

I need help regarding the did package developed by callaway and sant'anna in the context of an exercise for the university. The question that I am required to ask is:
Write a function that changes the most relevant input parameters and comment on their consequences:

- Effects window
- Compute the effects separately by region.

Can someone help me, give me a point from where I can start?

To answer the question I have used the dataset "mpdta" from callaway and Santanna.

Comment: Start with the part that you know how to do. If you don't know how to do any of it, start with a review of whatever course this is. (Sure, this is not very helpful, but we don't really want to encourage "here's my assignment, think for me"-type questions) [see also](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Welcome to SO Gabriele Gurrieri. Please review [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). The SO community are an incredibly helpful bunch, but in almost every case a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is expected. I realise this is difficult if you don't even know where to start, but your question needs some refinement in order for it to be answered.